# Set default language for fresh Drupal 8 install

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In Drupal 8 is there a way to automatically set the installation language for a new installation? I'll be basing it on the URL, I already have the logic to work out which language should be selected but unsure how to make it the default selection when doing a fresh install of Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you can populate the install state parameters via some URL queries. Adding `?langcode=en` would default it to English.

Otherwise, you would have to use a custom profile to ensure a proper default selection is made. The related code is in `core/includes/install.core.inc`. The `install_drupal` function is what performs Drupal's install. The langcode is determined in `install_begin_request` via the install state which is populated by `install_state_defaults`.

You'd need to get the langcode populated

```
if (!empty($install_state['parameters']['langcode'])) {
  $install_state['parameters']['langcode'] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z_0-9\-]/', '', $install_state['parameters']['langcode']);
}
```

Looking through the code, this is only possible via query parameters

```
// Add any installation parameters passed in via the URL.
if ($install_state['interactive']) {
  $install_state['parameters'] += $request->query->all();
}
```

Unless you had a custom install profile that invoked `hook_install_tasks` to add a task at the beginning of the install process to set the default language code.